# Can't go online after changed my mac address

Tags: fedora, wifi

```
[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig wlp2s0 down
[root@localhost ~]# macchanger -r wlp2s0
Current MAC:   xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (unknown)
Permanent MAC: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (unknown)
New MAC:       22:0d:81:f1:d3:82 (unknown)
[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig wlp2s0 up
[root@localhost ~]# macchanger -s wlp2s0
Current MAC:   22:0d:81:f1:d3:82 (unknown)
Permanent MAC: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (unknown)

ifconfig wlp2s0
wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.40  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether 22:0d:81:f1:d3:82  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 118031  bytes 144457184 (137.7 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 93120  bytes 20972827 (20.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

OS is Fedora 26 and the router is ZyXEL P-2601HN-F1.

There is wifi signal but I can't go online. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Where does the IP address come from, DHCP oder statically configured?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of ethereal/wireshark capture of your PC (use ARP/BOOTP filters)? This would help analyze further.

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# ifdown wlp2s0
usage: ifdown <device name>
[root@localhost ~]# ifconfig wlp2s0 hw ether 22:0d:81:f1:d3:82 
SIOCSIFHWADDR: Device or resource busy - you may need to down the interface.

Comment: IP comes from VPN IPv4 Method Automatic DHCP and IPv6 is set to Automatic. Thanks.

Comment: I have chaged OS to Ubuntu, creating new question on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/949130/cant-go-online-after-changed-my-mac-address

Answer (score 0):

Your Wi-Fi adapter may be unable to change its MAC address. You should check if it would send any packets with the new MAC address using another adapter and monitoring software like `kismet`.